# "eine Weile hin"-meaning

Tags: meaning-in-context

Here is a sentence:

> Vielleicht haben die Leute zu früh Silvester gefeiert-das ist noch eine Weile ***hin***, meine Damen und Herren.

I don't get how "hin" works here. Is it simply a stand-alone adverb meaning "away" in this context? I was under the impression that "her/hin" can only be used on their own after prepositional phrases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this context, *hin* is used in conjuction with *bis*, which is often omitted. In full length, you could write this sentence as

> [...] das ist noch eine Weile *bis* zu diesem Zeitpunkt *hin*.
>
> [...] das ist noch eine Weile *hin bis* zu diesem Zeitpunkt.
>
> [...] das ist noch eine Weile *bis* da*hin*. [...]

However since the object has already been stated, *bis zu diesem Zeitpunkt* (Silvester) can be omitted. However note that this is slightly informal, so when speaking or writing yourself, you have to find a balance between brevity and formality.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't get how "hin" may be used with "sein". I thought that the former is an adverb of direction used exclusively with verbs of motion

Comment: You can use it also as adverb of direction to an approximate point in time. E.g. "*Wann bist du fertig? Gegen Mittag hin [werde ich fertig sein].*" (very colloquial). A widely used composition with *hin* is *hin und wieder*, meaning something infrequent, e.g. "*Wie oft bestellst du Pizza? [Ich bestelle] Hin und wieder [Pizza].*"

Answer (score 2):

Hin and her can also be used to describe the direction of the passage of time.

- das ist noch eine Weile hin (Future)
- das ist schon eine Weile her (Past)

Answer (score 2):

The phrase means "there has still some time to pass (until New Year)".

"Hin" means "in a direction away from you", "her" means "towards you". Hier the "hin" is meant in a temporal manner instead of a spatial one:

There is still some time left until New Year. You are *here* in the now, so, from your perspective, it will take some (temporal) movement *away from you, into the future* to arrive at New Year.

As @swmgr said in his answer, would one talk about the past, the necessary temporal movement (of that event) would be *towards you*, hence "das ist eine Weile *her*" (that was some time ago).